# in one to many relationship more than one field comming while displaying in spring roo

Tags: java, spring-roo

In SPRING ROO I have Team and Person table with OneToMany relationship. While creating  team field is coming correctly as first name, but when go for list all teams then it is   displaying all values of person table, ie firstname, last name etc.

My code is something like this:

```
// Person with Team mapping
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "Fname")
private Set<Team> teams = new HashSet<Team>();
@ManyToOne
private Person Fname;
```

In list.jsp file I also used itemlabel but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

when you scaffolded your project, spring-roo created a class for you (ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean). In that class, you need to ensure that converters include only the fields that you'd like to display per dependent model object. Search for word "ToStringConverter" in your project's root. It should find the ones that spring-roo created for you by default in "AJ" files. Just redefine them in ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean based on your specification.

Comment: i just used what you have suggested,  it is working fine for me..Thnaks